# How can I use cookies on Webform?

Tags: 7, webforms, javascript, cookies

I'm using Drupal 7 and Webform and I want, remember input texts on next submissions for registered users.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

Try the [Webform Field Repeat](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_field_repeat)  module

> The Webform Field Repeat module enables the webform to remember selected field entries from current submission for up to an hour. It uses the $_SESSION to do so. If the session is active, the form will be populated with selected entries from remembered submission when opened again.

Comment: Yes, this module is working good but module ask to users for remember section. I want it automatically.